# Firebase hosting CSP nonce implementation

Tags: firebase, google-tag-manager, firebase-hosting, content-security-policy

I'm have been working on a CSP for my Firebase hosted website, a large number of request are block by the CSP because GTM (Google Tag Manager) is in inline script.

I'm using Firebase Analytics, which is the reason for GTM being injected into the page.
I have read that I can use a nonce [1], which in most cases is an non issue to implement.
How would this be implemented using Firebase hosting? - From my research Firebase hosting headers can't be modified after deployment.

1: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/web/csp

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can, you should have a firebase.json file in root of project folder, you can change your headers in it, check my file:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/browser",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|webp|eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=7200"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "**/*.@(html|js|css)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "X-Frame-Options",
            "value": "SAMEORIGIN"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "X-Content-Type-Options",
            "value": "nosniff"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Referrer-Policy",
            "value": "strict-origin"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Permissions-Policy",
            "value": "geolocation=(), microphone=(), gyroscope=()"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Unfortunately i was obligated to remove my csp from it...

Comment: The answer does not explain how to implement CSP 'nonce'. Only regular static CSP policies can be set using firebase hosting headers like this.
'Nonce' requires dynamic generation, that I believe can only be added using functions in firebase.